# how to catch up a html element with same class which is under different parent using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My markup is as follows:

```
<li class="item">
    <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="147" style="opacity: 0;">Quick View</div>
    <a class="product-image" title="xyz" href="http://def.com/xyz"><img alt="xyz" src="http://def.com/asdf">xyz</a>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a title="xyz" href="http://def.com/xyz">22" Syncmaster LCD Monitor</a></h2>
    <div class="price-box">something</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
    <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="163" style="opacity: 0;">Quick View</div>
    <a class="product-image" title="abc" href="http://def.com/abc"><img alt="abc" src="http://def.com/ghjk">abc</a>
    <h2 class="product-name"><a title="abc" href="http://def.com/abc">Another Product</a></h2>
   <div class="price-box">something</div>
</li>
```

I want to get the `data-pid` value of the second `quickview-btn` div on clicking the **first** `quickview-btn` div.

I used the `.parent()`, `.next()`, and `.closest()` methods in jQuery, but I'm not able to get it.

I tried:

```
$(this).parent('.item').next('.item').next('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
$(this).parent('.item').next('.item').child('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
$(this).parent('.item').next('.item').closest('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
```

but none of them worked for me.

```
$(this).parent('.item').next('.item').hide(); //this works
```

Comment: Clicking within the first `li` element, should retrieve the `data-pid` from the *second* `li` element?

Comment: is there a way i could straight away find the next occurrence and previous occurrence of ".quickview-btn" since I have four li's in a ul and n number of ul's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.quickview-btn').on('click',function(){
 var pid = $(this).closest('.item').next('.item').find('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
})
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/qSe6t/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  $('li.item').closest('.item').find('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.quickview-btn').on('click',function(){
    var pid = $(this).parent().next().find('.quickview-btn').attr('data-pid');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For direct access on load you can use this way. This is not recommended but one of the ways.

```
$("li:nth-child(2) .quickview-btn").data('pid');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code in addition to using the proper selectors, as follows:

```
$('li:first-child').find('.quickview-btn').on('click', function () {
    var nextData = $(this).parent().next().children('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
    console.log(nextData);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jSuAH/)