# How to find an element regardless of its level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento

this is similar to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984290/how-to-catch-up-a-html-element-with-same-class-which-is-under-different-parent-u).
sorry I don't know whether i could edit the same question.

so here is my requirement.
my HTML has the following part

```
<ul class="products-grid">
<li class="item">
    <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="101" style="opacity: 0;">Quick View</div>
    <!-- some other elements -->
</li>
<li class="item">
    <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="107" style="opacity: 0;">Quick View</div>
    <!-- some other elements -->
</li>
<li class="item">
    <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="123" style="opacity: 0;">Quick View</div>
    <!-- some other elements -->
</li>
<li class="item">
    <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="145" style="opacity: 0;">Quick View</div>
    <!-- some other elements -->
</li>
```

"I have n number of such unsorted lists"

when i click on one ".quickview-btn" div, i should get the "data-pid" value of next and previous (if exists) ".quickview-btn" divs, regardless, whetehr they are in next ul or previous ul.

> note: I cannot modify the html structure as i do many other operations keeping this structure in mind. so I cannot put all the li's in a single ul.

I am clueless as i'm new to jQuery. can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all `.quickview-btn` `div`s that are inside `.products-grid` `divs` like this:

```
var btns = $(".products-grid .quickview-btn");
```

Then find the index of the one that was clicked:

```
var index = btns.index(this);
```

Then you can use `-1` and `+1` to get the previous and next, *regardless* of what `ul` they're in:

```
var prev = btns.eq(index - 1).attr('data-pid');
var next = btns.eq(index + 1).attr('data-pid');
```

`prev` will be `undefined` for the first button. `next` will be `undefined` for the last.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Grid Clicks</title>
<style>
.quickview-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="products-grid">
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="101">Quick View</div>
        101
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="107">Quick View</div>
        107
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="123">Quick View</div>
        123
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="145">Quick View</div>
        145
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="products-grid">
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="201">Quick View</div>
        201
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="207">Quick View</div>
        207
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="223">Quick View</div>
        223
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <div class="quickview-btn" data-pid="245">Quick View</div>
        245
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $(".products-grid .quickview-btn").click(function() {
        var btns = $(".products-grid .quickview-btn");
        var index = btns.index(this);
        var prev = btns.eq(index - 1).attr('data-pid');
        var next = btns.eq(index + 1).attr('data-pid');
        alert(
          "You clicked: " + $(this).attr('data-pid') +
          "\nPrev: " + prev +
          "\nNext: " + next
          );
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/udakek/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/udakek/1/edit)

---

In the comments below you've said:

> ...but clicking next for last "quickview-btn" doesn't get first "quickview-btn" data-pid. May I know why is that?

Because there's nothing in the above to implement that wrapping. It doesn't magically happen.

If you want wrapping: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/udakek/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/udakek/2/edit)

```
var btns = $(".products-grid .quickview-btn");
var index = btns.index(this);
var count = btns.length;
var prev = btns.eq((index + (count - 1)) % count).attr('data-pid');
var next = btns.eq((index + 1) % count).attr('data-pid');
```

Comment: I am afraid that it wont fetch the value from the previous ul. will it?

Comment: @Shathish: Fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: @Shathish: `prev` & `next` won't fetch elements out of the current parent. So, you don't have to afraid about that.

Comment: @TamilVendhan: My impression is that he *does* want them to.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: ah.. I misunderstood.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: yeah that works like what i exactly expected! I learnt a new method "index" today. Thank you very much.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: actually this works in cycle; clicking prev for first "quickview-btn" shows last [that's good]. but clicking next for last "quickview-btn" doesn't get first "quickview-btn" data-pid. May I know why is that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: sorry about that, I just wanted to know why was that. And thanks for providing me the idea of wrapping, this is an added gift!

Comment: @Shathish: :-) No worries!

Answer (score 0):

here I tried this and it works for me.
if there is a perfect way please let me know.

```
$('.quickview-btn').on('click', function () {
var nextId = $(this).closest('.item').next('.item').find('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
var prevId = $(this).closest('.item').prev('.item').find('.quickview-btn').data('pid');

if(!nextId){
   nextId = $(this).closest('.products-grid').next('.products-grid').find('.quickview-btn').data('pid');
}
if(!prevId){
    $(this).closest('.products-grid').prev('.products-grid').find('.quickview-btn').each(function(){
        prevId = $(this).data('pid');
    });
}
```

console.log(prevId, nextId);
});